# Add 1 second of silence to the .wav sound file

Tags: matlab

I need to create a function in MATLAB, but I'm new to the program so I would appreciate any help from you guys. I've read the other posts here, but unfortunately none have helped me.

Here's the question: **How can I add 1 second of silence to both the beginning and the ending of a WAV file with MATLAB?**

My current code:

```
subplot(2,1,1)
[s1,Fs]=wavread('sound.wav');
t=linspace(0,1,Fs);
plot(t,s1)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I've tried combining 2 .wav files - original and a file with a second of silence. But that doesn't meet the requirements of the task. I've also tried creating a matrix of zeros but that didn't work out well since i'm new to this program and don't know the specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Create a vector of zeros. (size of vector will depend on sampling rate).

```
silence = zeros(Fs, 1);
finalWav = [silence s1 silence];
```

Step 2: Concatenate the vectors.

That should do it. 
Please note, that I do not have access to Matlab and am not able to test the code.